# QTextEdit and QPrintPreview works slowly with large HTML table

Tags: python, performance, pyqt, qtextedit, qprinter

I'm trying to create reports like MS Access, and thanks to QTextEdit example everything works very nicely. But when I open a large HTML table (about 5000 rows), it takes about 35 seconds to load the table - so it's very slow. How can I optimise the print-preview? Maybe load only one page and change the current page in the print-preview window? But I can't find how to access the print-preview buttons. Or maybe change something with my HTML table?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TextEdit(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, fileName=None, parent=None):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupFileActions()
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

        if fileName is None:
            fileName = './test5000.htm'
            self.load(fileName)

    def load(self, f):
        if not QtCore.QFile.exists(f):
            return False

        fh = QtCore.QFile(f)
        if not fh.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly):
            return False

        data = fh.readAll()
        codec = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForHtml(data)
        unistr = codec.toUnicode(data)

        if QtCore.Qt.mightBeRichText(unistr):
            self.textEdit.setHtml(unistr)
        else:
            self.textEdit.setPlainText(unistr)
        return True

    def setupFileActions(self):
        menu = QtGui.QMenu("&File", self)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(menu)

        self.actionOpen = QtGui.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme('document-open'),
            "&Open...", self, shortcut=QtGui.QKeySequence.Open,
            triggered=self.fileOpen)
        menu.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        menu.addSeparator()

        self.actionPrintPreview = QtGui.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme('fileprint'),
            "Print Preview...", self,
            shortcut=QtCore.Qt.CTRL + QtCore.Qt.SHIFT + QtCore.Qt.Key_P,
            triggered=self.filePrintPreview)
        menu.addAction(self.actionPrintPreview)

    def fileOpen(self):
        fn = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File...", "C:",
                                           "HTML-Files (*.htm *.html);;All Files (*)")
        if fn:
            self.load(fn)

    def filePrintPreview(self):
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)

        printer.setOrientation(1)
        printer.setPageSize(8)
        printer.setPageMargins(20, 20, 20, 20, 0)
        printer.setResolution(300)

        preview = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(printer, self)
        preview.paintRequested.connect(self.printPreview)
        preview.exec_()

    def printPreview(self, printer):
        self.textEdit.print_(printer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindows = []
    for fn in sys.argv[1:] or [None]:
        textEdit = TextEdit(fn)
        textEdit.resize(1024, 768)
        textEdit.show()
        mainWindows.append(textEdit)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sample HTML file with images is [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09614071865472894084).

When you run script it opens the HTML file (slowly), then menu File->Print preview runs the print-preview dialog.

Comment: If you do not show your code we can not know if the error is caused by your code

Comment: But there is no error, I'm just asking for some advices about perfomance of PrintPreview...

Comment: How do you assume that your code is optimal? that there are no syntax errors does not imply that there is unnecessary code, or use inappropriate classes that lead to unnecessary memory or resources.

Comment: I add code of PrintPreview part (or I should add all class?)

Comment: @pythoff. You need to provide a small, self-contained script which creates/loads an html table and then shows it in a print-preview dialog. This doesn't have to *exactly* match your real code - it just needs to replicate the slow performance. That way, other people can simply run your script to see if they can reproduce the problem. The screenshots in your question are completely useless, because they can't be used for testing. You need to provide the *actual html file* that is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edit my question

Comment: @pythoff. For such a large html table (with images), it is really no surprise that it takes so long to load. Even with firefox, the performance is not much different. You obviously need to split the table up into multiple pages somehow, and then display/print them separately. See [this qt forum thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37851-problem-printing-a-multi-page-report) for some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks a lot for help! I found QPrintPreview**Widget**, that allows to create my own interface for print preview! I can't figure out why I didn't find it before:D

Comment: @ekhumoro, is it possible to change page number in PrintPreviewWidget? I'm displaying my table one page at a time, but it everytime shows that it's page number 1.

Comment: @pythoff. I suppose [setCurrentPage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprintpreviewwidget.html#setCurrentPage) should do that.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I mean not to choose from set of pages, I just want to change/delete a digit of [displaying page](https://imgur.com/a/lWpig). I tried to set all margins to 0, and in print preview it looks fine (page number goes beyond page border). But when I print pages there are still page number. **In general**, I don't want page numeration. Is it possible?

Comment: @pythoff. It is not appropriate to discus this further in comments. Please post a new question, so that others can participate.